# extract first word from a sentence and store it

Tags: regex, perl

i am extracting first word from a line using regex in Perl

```
for my $source_line (@lines) {
    $source_line =~ /^(.*?)\s/
}
```

But I want to store the first word into a variable

when I print the below code, I get correct output

```
print($source_line =~ /^(.*?)\s/)
```

when I want to store in $i and print it, I get output as 1.

```
my $i =  ($source_line =~ /^(.*?)\s/);
print $i;
```

How do the store the first word into a temporary variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the match in list context.

```
my ($i) = $source_line =~ /^(.*?)\s/;
```

`my ($i)` is the same as `(my $i)`, which "looks like a list", so it causes `=` to be the list assignment operator, and the list assignment operator evaluates its RHS in list context.

---

By the way, the following version works even if there's only one work and when there's leading whitespace:

```
my ($i) = $source_line =~ /(\S+)/;
```

Comment: there won't be any leading space thats y i used /^(.*?)\s/ but you are right its better to use /(\S+)/

Comment: Then you can use `/^(\S+)/` for its self-documenting aspects, but it's effectively going to be the same as `/(\S+)/`

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to context, this expression:

```
$source_line =~ /^(.*?)\s/
```

returns a list of matches.

When you evaluate a list in list context, you get the list itself back. When you evaluate a list in scalar context, you get the size of the list back; which is what is happening here.

So changing your lhs expression to be in list context:

```
my ($i) = $source_line =~ /^(.*?)\s/;
```

captures the word correctly.

There were recently a few articles on Perl Weekly related to context, here is one of them that was particularly good: http://perlhacks.com/2013/12/misunderstanding-context/